# How to download map tiles for Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, openstreetmap, maptiler

I understand that this is a basic question; however, I've spent hours googling and have yet to find an answer that works.

I have a javascript webapp that uses Leaflet to display a map. I can get it to work when the tile source URL is some online repository like mapbox, but I want my application to work offline. How/where can I download tiles and save them in a folder structure that I can then set the tile source URL to point to?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an offline Map layer available for Leaflet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34408079/is-there-an-offline-map-layer-available-for-leaflet)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate tiles by yourself using same engine as OSM's : [Mapnik](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mapnik) and OSM database.

Comment: If you follow https://switch2osm.org/manually-building-a-tile-server-16-04-2-lts/ you'll have a tile server that you can copy tiles from that will look the same as OSM's standard layer.  That isn't the most efficient format for offline tiles though.